# not complete SQL output

Tags: mysql, sql

If I write:

```
SELECT * FROM `expense`
```

I'll get

```
2022-02-17 10 bread
2022-02-23 20 perfume
```

but if I put this:

```
SELECT expense_date, amount, description, sum(amount) as total
FROM expense
```

The query gives me the LAST item. How do I get ALL items like I get with

```
SELECT *
```

I tried

```
SELECT *, sum(amount) as total
FROM expense
```

but no dice :(

Comment: Using `sum(amount)` without GROUP BY clause causes implicit GROUP BY. In this case the whole rowset is treated as single group. Hence only one output row is produced. The values of another columns are taken from indefinite (close to randomly selected) row - this is an effect of your current SQL server mode. Enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY - and your query will fail.

Comment: I.e. your current query is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could use `SUM()` as an analytic function with a window over the entire table:

```sql
SELECT expense_date, amount, description, SUM(amount) OVER () AS total
FROM expense;
```

This would output:

```
expense_date | amount | description | total
2022-02-17   | 10     | bread       | 30
2022-02-23   | 20     | perfume     | 30
```

Answer (score 0):

`SUM()` is an aggregate function. Summing only one record is no sense.

See [group by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) to get the total amount of different date.

```
SELECT 
    expense_date,
    description, 
    sum(amount) as total
FROM
    expense
GROUP BY expense_date,description
ORDER BY description;
```